# React Native - Accessing drawer navigation outside of AppNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-native-drawer

```
  App.js 
    <Store>
      <Navbar />
      <AppNavigator ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }} />
    </Store>
```

I wanna be able to access

```
 props.navigation.openDrawer();
```

from navbar but I get

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.openDrawer')

onPress
    Navbar.js:70:29
    etc..
```

How can I allow NavBar to access the drawer?

Comment: what is React Navigation version??

Comment: for accessing React Navigation outer of component or appNavigator you can use follow official React Navigation document: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are following [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) (if you don't then you should in your case). Then in `NavigationService.js` add openDrawer method

```
// NavigationService.js

import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

...

// add this function
function openDrawer(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
}


export default {
  ...
  // and export it
  openDrawer
};
```

then instead of `props.navigation.openDrawer()`, use

```
NavigationService.openDrawer()
```

don't forget to make respective imports

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Max Can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607272/how-to-add-drawer-in-react-native

Answer (score 3):

this is how i used openDrawer without navigation prop:

in your App.js (or other router)

1/

```
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

2/

```
export const navigationRef = React.createRef();
```

3/

```
export function openDrawer(routeName, params) {
  navigationRef.current.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
}
```

4/ inside your navigation container add this ref

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
```

5/ call your function somewhere where openDrawer is created:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openDrawer()}>
        <Image
          source={tab}
          style={{
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
          }}
        />
</TouchableOpacity>
```